# Jetpack compose Dialog with CircularProgressIndicator not shown

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have this composable

```
@Composable
fun LoadingDialog(loading: Boolean, onDismissRequest: ()->Unit) {

    println("loading = " + loading)

    if (loading) {
        Dialog(
            onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
            DialogProperties(dismissOnBackPress = false, dismissOnClickOutside = false)
        ) {

            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            ) {
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to visualize it during an http calls in this way

```
if (isLoading.value)
    LoadingDialog(loading = isLoading.value, onDismissRequest = { isLoading.value = false })
```

and the http something like this:

```
 if (executeHttpLogin.value) {

        isLoading.value = true

        httpLogin(
            executeHttpLogin.value,
            username.value.text,
            password.value.text,
            preferenceHelper,
            onResultSuccess = { loginResponse ->
                isLoading.value = false
                HttpLoginResponseSuccess(
                    loginResponse,
                    showSelezionaRuoloDialog,
                    navController,
                    preferenceHelper,
                    gruppi
                )
            }, onResultError = { message ->
                isLoading.value = false
                Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
        )

        executeHttpLogin.value = false

    }
```

The isLoading is

```
val isLoading = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

But the Dialog never shown. There is a way to visualize the CircularProgressIndicator() in the Dialog?

Comment: can you share how did you declare **isLoading** variable?

Comment: I have solved using coroutines like this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68791910/4399386)

Answer (score 0):

In your current design you are exposing events to your UI and doing it while you remove block below

```
if (executeHttpLogin.value) {

}
```

from composition by setting `executeHttpLogin.value = false`

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#5

You might create side-effects with your approach since the time you get result your block exits composition. Instead of this you should consider a UI state that covers different situations such as Loading, Success and Error.

You can either move http request to ViewModel and observe UiState in your Composable or ,if you don't want to use a ViewModel, you can consider using `producestate`

this way instead of multiple flags to change UI you can do such as

```
when(uiState){
 Loading->  LoadingDialog()
 Success-> SuccessUI()
 Error-> ErroUI
}
```

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#producestate

Comment: Thanks, could you explain better the produceState approach starting from my example?